# Multiple conditional If statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have written a conditional statement like below.The idea or objective of this statement is to check a set of condition against another set of conditions.

It looks like below:

```
else if ((Convert.ToString(dRow[UtilityEntity.FranceColumnGS]) == "x" || 
          Convert.ToString(dRow[UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHQ]) == "x" ||
          Convert.ToString(dRow[UtilityEntity.FranceColumnIO]) == "x" || 
          Convert.ToString(dRow[UtilityEntity.FranceColumnJM]) == "x") && 
         (Convert.ToString(dRow[UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHB]) == "x" || 
          Convert.ToString(dRow[UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHZ]) == "x" || 
          Convert.ToString(dRow[UtilityEntity.FranceColumnIX]) == "x" || 
          Convert.ToString(dRow[UtilityEntity.FranceColumnJV]) == "x"))
{
    excelWorksheet.Cells["AV" + rowIndex].Value = "both";
}
```

It works at the moment but I know for sure this can be reduced to be more efficient.

Can anyone suggest or provide some hint how can this statement shorten.

Comment: I don't know about efficient but I think it can be made a lot more readable and maintanable

Comment: Personally it seems to be even a problem at the source. Why do you have so much similar columns?

Comment: A switch statement may be nicer, for readability and maintainability.  Especially since it looks like it may change quite frequently.

Comment: Are you sure you need all the conversions to string? what is it's type beforehand?

Comment: Basically excel structure being parsed is fixed.

Comment: I assume if you post the previous else-if-blocks that this could be even more simplified. I have the feeling that you are looking for similar conditions before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is efficient enough. You are using `||` and `&&` which use lazy evaluation, so as soon as the outcome is known, the rest of the expressions will no longer be evaluated.

It could be made a lot more readable and with less typing, though.

```
if (isX(UtilityEntity.FranceColumnGS) || isX(UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHQ) ...)
{
   ...
}


private bool isX(int index)
{
    return (Convert.ToString(dRow[index]) == "x");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As a sample how it can be done:

```
var firstConditionColumns = new[] {
    UtilityEntity.FranceColumnGS,
    UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHQ,
    UtilityEntity.FranceColumnIO,
    UtilityEntity.FranceColumn.JM };
var secondConditionColumns = new[] {
    UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHB,
    UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHZ,
    UtilityEntity.FranceColumnIX,
    UtilityEntity.FranceColumnJV };
if (firstConditionColumns.Any(o => Convert.ToString(dRow[o]) == "x") &&
    secondConditionColumns.Any(o => Convert.ToString(dRow[o]) == "x"))
{
    excelWorksheet.Cells["AV" + rowIndex].Value = "both";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make an extension method for dbRow. I'm not sure what that class is called in your example, but as an example I assume it's DbRow:

```
public static class DbRowExtension
{
    public static bool AnyColIsChecked(this DbRow source, string[] colNames)
    {
        return colNames.Any(x => source[x] == "X");
    }
}
```

You could then write your if-statement like this

```
if (dbRow.AnyColIsChecked(UtilityEntity.FranceColumnGS,
        UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHQ,
        UtilityEntity.FranceColumnIO,
        UtilityEntity.FranceColumn.JM) &&
    dbRow.AnyColIsChecked(UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHB,
        UtilityEntity.FranceColumnHZ,
        UtilityEntity.FranceColumnIX,
        UtilityEntity.FranceColumnJ))
{
    ...
}
```